# Getting error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::resize' even when I make sure that the frame to be resized is not none

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I've been stuck in this issue for weeks, I would really appreciate it if you help me in it.
So here is the workflow of my project in a nutshell:

1. Get input stream from live cameras
2. Extract frame
3. Run an AI pipeline over that frame (object detection, object tracking)
4. Save the results
5. Call function (visualize) that will change the color of the bounding box from AI results based on a condition (either red or green)

Long story short, the whole workflow used to work well until I did some changes in IPC, where previously, each camera used to connect to the system through separate ports, while I unified the port for both of them (using ZMQ multi-pup model), now I get this error in the resize function whenever I call the visualizer function:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3)
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-u4kjpz2z\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4057:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Here is the code of the visualizer function:

```py
    def visualize_intrusion(self, frame, intrusion_rois, tracks, stats, polygon_color):
            red_marked = []
            rois = []
            for intrusion_roi in intrusion_rois:
                for obj in tracks.Tracked_Objects:
                    ########       GETTING BBOX AND ID       ########
                    left, top, right, bottom = int(obj.bbox[0]), int(obj.bbox[1]), int(obj.bbox[2]), int(obj.bbox[3])
                    label = str(obj.Id)
    
                    ########       SETTING BOX COLOR       ########
                    if obj.Id in red_marked:
                        continue
                    box_color = green if not stats[intrusion_roi['region_id']][obj.Id]['in_roi'] else red
                    if box_color == red:
                        red_marked.append(obj.Id)
    
                    ########       PUTTING CONTENT ON THE FRAME       ########
                    self.draw_curved_bbox(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), box_color, 3, 10, 15)
                    label_size, base_line = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
                    top = max(top, label_size[1])
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top - label_size[1]), (left + label_size[0], top + int(base_line * 0.3)), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                    cv2.putText(frame, label, (left, top), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    
                # if is_intrusion:
                rois.append(intrusion_roi['polygon'])
    
            self.draw_polygon(frame, rois, type=polygon_color)
    
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=self.resize_factor, fy=self.resize_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            
            return frame
```

Although I have a condition that skips the frame if it is none, this error continues to occur. I tried to print the frame.shape that is corresponding to the error and I got

> (1, 2, 3)

meaning it was too small to get resized but I don't know how did that happen or how to stop the frames from getting this small in the iteration!

Here is the trace of frame size before and after calling the function visualize:

```
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (239, 424, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (239, 424, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (112, 199, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (112, 199, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (53, 94, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (53, 94, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (25, 44, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (25, 44, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (12, 21, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (12, 21, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (6, 10, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (6, 10, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (3, 5, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (3, 5, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (1, 2, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1080, 1920, 3)
Resize factor repr ===> 0.47
Frame Shape (After Visualizer):===> (508, 902, 3)
Frame Shape (Before Visualizer):===> (1, 2, 3)
```

The ideal approach is that it always be `1080x1920` before, because I always get the freshest frame from the live stream, and always be `508x902` after so I send it and display it in the gui.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @DrBwts the code is kinda huge but I shared the relevant function for this matter. Noting that I have a condition that checks if elements to be passed are not none.

Comment: what is the size of the frame prior to processing? I cant see anything in the code you have provided that would change the size of the frame unless one of your `draw` methods is doing something

Comment: input is *probably* irrelevant. **`dsize`** is a 2-tuple you have to pass, except if fx and fy are given... and it would calculate `dsize` given those two and the input's size. -- `print(frame.shape)` as well as `print(repr(self.resize_factor))` and report back. my bet is on resize_factor being zero. if that is the case, you'll need to learn to debug your code more thoroughly. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @DrBwts the size of frame prior to processing is 1080 x 1920, and `draw` methods do nothing to the frame itself but placing lines and shapes on it. I added the trace of frame sizes before and after calling the function, please check them.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the resize factor is constant to 0.47, I added the trace of frame sizes please check them. The thing is this function works perfectly in the main branch so I don't know where the problem is. Thank you for the link, it is helpful as a newbie in StackOverflow :)

Comment: you notice the frame shrinking infinitely. now you just have to step through your program and wonder what your variables are doing. your code is incomplete (not a MRE). we can't help with that now.